# Why do images on the rear display of my Nikon D5500 look cartoon-like?

Tags: troubleshooting, rear-lcd, nikon-d5500

[image]

I think I turned on a setting that makes my pictures look cartoon-like when displayed using the playback image on Nikon. Please see image below of a screen shot of what I see on the Nikon. When I download the picture, it looks normal and in focus. This picture was used taking Auto and not special settings. Please advice how to turn off this setting. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

From the Nikon [website](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product-archive/dslr-cameras/d5200.html) for the D5200, the camera is able to apply [posterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization) on the pictures you take :

> And an exciting collection of built-in effects and filters opens new possibilities for expression: isolate a single color, explore black & white, **posterize**, miniaturize

In the [D5500 user reference](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/ETOYI00bfdW602XchPU57r5bLc70/D5500RM_(En)03.pdf) page 61, the effect "Photo illustration" seems to match what you observe. Try changing the mode dial from the "effects" mode to auto mode or P mode. Now, your photos should look normal again.

Comment: What is "posterization"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue happening today so I looked up for some answers but none of them matched... but I figured where it came from !!
The problem was in the wires between the gear and the monitor ! The D550 has a rotating screen, which I suppose make the connection much more fragile. I noticed the “cartoon like” style, separating the colours, was not only in my pictures but anywhere else as well (try to check it by yourself).
I managed to solve the issue by moving the screen... now I can see the colours correctly but only in one position, I guess the wires aren’t too damaged.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score -5):

Guessing what you may mean?   If "cartoon-like" means the dogs head looks disproportionately large (it does to me), then all you need to  do is to step back a few feet with the camera. The camera being too close distorts the perspective (the proportions of the close parts). Always stand back 6 or 7 feet for better perspective in photos, and then feel free to zoom back in all you wish for any framing you desire.  Zooming in won't hurt, but standing too close will.  Perspective depends on where the camera stands.

The "rings" on the mans arm around the dog are due to moire effects, which is optical interference between the camera sensors grid pattern and the camera LED screen grid pattern.  Photographing a LED screen up close is difficult that way.  You could **very slightly** defocus the camera lens until the interference is blurred away and disappears.  Standing back more probably helps that too.

Comment: re: 2nd paragraph: that doesn't register as moiré to me. It just looks like posterization, rather than grid pattern interference.

Comment: Yup. Agree on the posterization thing.